# Table inside table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I have a table which contains another table in reactjs. I've inserted a button inside each row of the outer table and when I clicked this I trigger an action for showing the nested table. My code is like this:

```
{slipsList.map((slip, i) =>
              <tbody>
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td className="table-sticky--first-col">
                    {slip.confirmationDate}
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => hideButtonClicked()}
                    >{i}</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.slipNumber}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.country}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.side}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.grossAmount}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.commission}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.feesPerStampDuty}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.tax}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.netAmount}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    {slip.netAmountEuro}
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr
                  className={classnames({ hide_element: slipsHide })}
                >
                  <td colSpan="10">
                    {renderInside(slip)}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            )}
```

When a user clicks the  button in a row this row must collapse. My problem is that with my implementation when I click the button all the rows of the table are collapsed. My `renderInside` function is the following:

```
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {renderInstrumentInfo(slip.prodType,
              slip.symbol, slip.exchange,
              slip.country, slip.name)}
            </td>
            <td>{slip.type}</td>
            <td>{slip.quantity}</td>
            <td>{slip.price}</td>
            <td>{slip.amount}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is `slipsHide` in this line, `className={classnames({ hide_element: slipsHide })}` . Can you show ur constructor ?

Comment: slipHide is a boolean value. When i click the button it becomes true or false and the hide_element class is applied or not

Answer (score 1):

Passing the index of the row that you want to show or hide will help

Set up an `onClick` method and pass the index like

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => hideButtonClicked(i)}
>{i}</button>
```

And in redux `mapDispatchToProps()`, pass an argument to get the index and pass it 
like

```
mapStateToProps = dispatch => (
      {hideButtonClicked: (index) => {
                dispatch(expandCollapseClicked('slips', index))
           }
      })
```

Comment: With that way i need to redefine my action export function expandCollapseClicked(component) {
  return {
    type: EXPAND_COLLAPSE_CLICKED,
    payload: {
      component
    }
  };
}

Comment: Yes you will need to do that so that you can handle individual rows differently

Comment: Is there a more rapid way to achieve this? Maybe call className inside the other function. I dont want to change the expand collapse action because i use it in many components

Comment: You can simply create a new function that does it for you and whose implementation is the same as expandCollapse function and use that,

Comment: I made it but it doesnt work, the className={classnames({ hide_element: slipsHide[i] })} applies the value true or false to all the rows of the nestred table

Comment: how do i apply className={classnames({ hide_element: slipsHide[i] })} in my table??

Comment: Is classnames a function

Comment: it's a module which add a className dynamically

Comment: Are you setting the slipsHide[i] value according to the index of the row clicked

Answer (score 0):

Reason is, you are using single `bool` for all the rows, instead of that use an `array` of `bool` values, each value for each row, like this:

```
<tr
   className={classnames({ hide_element: slipsHide[i] })}
>
```

And `onClick` of button change only that particular `bool`, not the all values. To update the specific value you need to pass the `index` of each item into `onClick` method, like this:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => hideButtonClicked(i)}
>{i}</button>
```

Now use this `index` in `hideButtonClicked` method:

```
hideButtonClicked(index){
  //now update only slipsHide[index]
}
```

Comment: I've thought of your idea but i have a problem. My hideButtonClicked is generated through mapDispatchToProps like this: const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    hideButtonClicked: () => {
      dispatch(expandCollapseClicked('slips'));
    }
  }
);. How to add i when i dispatch it? Sorry for the foolish question but i'm pretty new to react and js :)

Comment: and slipHide through mapStateToProps like this: slipsHide: userSettingsState(state).get('slipsHide')

Comment: @Shubham i don't know much about redux, answered this ques, he is using `const mapDispatchToProps ` help him to pass index in onclick method, check the above comment how he is handling the events.

Comment: change definition to `mapStateToProps = dispatch => ({hideButtonClicked: (index) => {dispatch(expandCollapseClicked('slips', index))}})`

Comment: please add that in a separate answer.